# Volume of revolution of a region bounded by the $x$- axis

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

So I have this problem which says:

''The plane region bounded above by the curves $x=y^2$ and $x+y=2$ and below by the $x$-axis is rotated about the line $y=2$. The volume of the obtained solid of revolution is...''

I'm a little confused as to how to set up the region. I sketched the region but I am not really sure how to do it. The function definition changes at $1$ so I don't think the method of rings is appropriate here. So I then tried to use the shell method with:

$$A(y)=2\pi(y-2)(2-y-y^2)$$ which I thought was right but if I integrate that, I get 0 which I don't think is right. That doesn't make sense.

Could anyone tell me where I went wrong and help me set up the integral? Thanks a lot...

Comment: I think it should be 2-y instead of y-2.  What are you using for the limits?

Comment: @randomgirl: Sorry if I preempted your hint -- I didn't look at the comments before posting.

Comment: I think we posted right about at the same time anyway.

Comment: I used 0 and 1 for the limits.

Comment: That is right... Don't know how you got 0 from that... Maybe something bad happen in your integration or simplification.

Comment: No I switched my radius around. I used y-2 instead of 2-y. Can you explain why that is the case?

Comment: Even if you had $y-2$ instead of $2-y$, that would only change the sign of the answer, so you must have made some other error as well.

Comment: In my previous comment, I was talking about the height, not the radius. The correct radius is $(2-y) - y^2$ (rightmost $x$-value minus the leftmost $x$-value), which in my posted answer, is shown as $2-y-y^2$.

Comment: @quasi The axis of rotation is the line $y=2$. So, $2-y-y^2$ does not refer to the radius. Rather, it refers to length of the horizontal strip. See  the graph in my answer below.

Comment: @Right, my mistake. When I worked out the integral, I had the correct diagram, and the correct radius and height (after some alerts from randomgirl). But in my comment, I wasn't looking, and I confused the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy is right.

The correct integral is

$$\int_{0}^1 2\pi(2-y)(2-y-y^2)\, dy$$

which evaluates to $\displaystyle{\frac{23\pi}{6}}$.

Comment: Right -- I always read too fast (I read it the way I wanted it to be!). I'll edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh! -- Feel free to give me a -1 (I deserve it).

Comment: lol. I gave you a plus 1. :)

Comment: Why is it 2-y and not y-2?

Comment: y=2 is above the points in the region... any point you find in the region will have a y-coordinate less than y=2.

Comment: The height is the positive length (bigger minus smaller). Thus, $2 - y$.

Comment: Ahh yes yes of course. Thanks very much haha.

Answer (score 2):

The shaded area is the region that we are looking for.
[image]

If we rotate the shaded region about the line $y=2$, then using the Shell Method, we get
$$V=\int_{0}^1 2\pi(2-y)\cdot \big[(2-y)-y^2\big]dy=\frac{23\pi}{6}.$$